# Como convertir esta funcion de switch a if?

Tags: javascript, condiciones

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
var config = service.getConfiguration();
switch (config.type) {
  case 'pattern':
    $wrapper.find('.pattern-library li').removeClass('selected');
    $wrapper.find('.' + config.extra.replace(' ', '.')).addClass('selected');
    $wrapper.find('.btn-picker-pattern').css({'background-color': config.color});
  break;
  case 'color':
    $wrapper.find('.btn-picker-color').css({'background-color': config.color});
  break;
  case 'image':
    $wrapper.find('#image_position_chzn').remove();
    $imagePositionSelector.val(config.extra).removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();
  break;
}
$('body').trigger('menu-configuration-update');
};
```

y para arreglar un error que contiene, necesito agregar esta condición:

```
if ( !$.isEmptyObject(config.extra) ) { 
  $wrapper.find( '.' + config.extra.replace(' ', '.') ).addClass('selected');
```

Entonces pienso que seria mejor trasladar todo a `if` o sino una manera de poder insertar la condición en mi función actual. Como podría hacerlo?

Comment: Donde te da el error? Y que error te da?

Comment: entiendo que ese if lo tenes que agregar en, case 'pattern' y case 'image', correcto?

Comment: Por lo que entiendo de tu problema, la condición del `if` es independiente de las del `switch`, por lo que podría ir antes o después de este

Comment: @SaúlHormazábal gracias por tu respuesta, debajo deje el comentario de lo que me sucede actualmente.

Comment: @FabrizioMigotto gracias por tu respuesta, debajo deje el comentario de lo que me sucede actualmente

Comment: @IñigoIrigoyenErquicia gracias por tu respuesta, debajo deje el comentario de lo que me sucede actualmente

Comment: @NicolasSeguro Te recomiendo que mejores la descripción de tu pregunta incluyendo tu nuevo problema, en lugar de dejarla como respuesta

Comment: @NicolasSeguro También podrías agregar un ejemplo del contenido de la variable `config`

Answer (score 1):

Al utilizar ese if resolví mi error de **"Cannot read replace property",** pero Ahora hace que no quede seleccionada la clase que es elegida como fondo en mi menu y ese seria *mi problema ahora*, entonces como podria hacerlo correctamente?

```
var config = service.getConfiguration();

            switch (config.type) {
                case 'pattern':
                    $wrapper.find('.pattern-library li').removeClass('selected');

                    if (!$.isEmptyObject(config.extra)) { 
                        $wrapper.find('.' + config.extra.replace(' ', '.')).addClass('selected');
                    }

                    $wrapper.find('.btn-picker-pattern').css({'background-color': config.color});
                    break;
                case 'color':
                    $wrapper.find('.btn-picker-color').css({'background-color': config.color});
                    break;
                case 'image':
                    $wrapper.find('#image_position_chzn').remove();
                    $imagePositionSelector.val(config.extra).removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();
                    break;
            }
            $('body').trigger('menu-configuration-update');
        };
```

Comment: Si tienes una nueva pregunta, la puedes formular haciendo clic en el botón [Formular una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Incluye un enlace a esta pregunta si ayuda a proporcionar contexto. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/148983)

Comment: gracias @RaulCacacho https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/251928/118416 este es el link de la nueva pregunta.