# no queda seleccionada la clase que es elegida

Tags: javascript, clase, condiciones

Al utilizar ese if resolví mi error de "Cannot read replace property" en [Como convertir esta funcion de switch a if? + no queda seleccionada la clase que es elegida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/251902/118416), pero Ahora hace que no quede seleccionada la clase que es elegida como fondo en mi menu y ese seria mi problema ahora, entonces como podria hacerlo correctamente?

```
var config = service.getConfiguration();

            switch (config.type) {
                case 'pattern':
                    $wrapper.find('.pattern-library li').removeClass('selected');

                    if (!$.isEmptyObject(config.extra)) { 
                        $wrapper.find('.' + config.extra.replace(' ', '.')).addClass('selected');
                    }

                    $wrapper.find('.btn-picker-pattern').css({'background-color': config.color});
                    break;
                case 'color':
                    $wrapper.find('.btn-picker-color').css({'background-color': config.color});
                    break;
                case 'image':
                    $wrapper.find('#image_position_chzn').remove();
                    $imagePositionSelector.val(config.extra).removeClass('chzn-done').chosen();
                    break;
            }
            $('body').trigger('menu-configuration-update');
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucioné reemplazando mi IF anterior por:

```
 if (typeof config.value === 'string' ) {
     $wrapper.find('.' + config.value.replace(' ', '.')).addClass('selected');
  }
```

ya que extra debia ser reemplazado por value.